# php mysql storing line breaks in text area in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, format

I have an input textarea and I would like to store the line breaks that a user makes in the text area in the database, so that it echoes the output text the same way as in the input text

eg:

```
Some text some text some text some text


new line some text some text new line 

new line some text new line some text
```

this is my current upload script:

```
$sql = "insert into people (price, contact, category, username, fname, lname, expire, filename) values (:price, :contact, :category, :user_id, :fname, :lname, now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, :imagename)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql) or die("failed!");
$q->bindParam(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':contact', $contact, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(':imagename', $imagename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
```

Comment: As per Micah's comment, try adding `nl2br` to your output, i.e. `nl2br($imagename);`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, say if it was the lname output that i wanted to preserve the line breaks, how i would do that and where i would place

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The line breaks in the text area are linebreak characters such as `\n`. These are not rendered in HTML and thus they won't show up if you simply echo the output. You can echo inside of a `<textarea>` or a `<pre>` tag or you can use the [`nl2br()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to replace new lines with `<br>` tags so that it can be displayed as HTML.

Comment: thankyou for your reply, i am unsure where i would put the nl2br(), it is the "lname" text that i want to preserve the line breaks

Comment: That would be in the PHP that *displays* the output. That is, the linebreaks are stored in the DB but the display of that data needs to be parsed before displaying as HTML. `echo nl2br($data);`

Comment: thanks, i have tried that but it literally say nl2br(some text); when i echo

Comment: echo "<div id='expanderContent' style='display:none'><div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1'> nl2br($lname); </div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Contact:<br /> ". $row['contact'] . "</div></div>";

Comment: echo "<div id='expanderContent' style='display:none'><div class='reasonbar'><div class='prod-title1'>". nl2br($lname); ."</div><div class='reason1' style='width: 29%;'>Contact:<br /> ". $row['contact'] . "</div></div>";

Comment: it comes up with an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Comment: Sorry, remove the semicolon after `nl2br($lname)`

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the line breaks before storing by using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

you can also use javascript to break the text as `\n to <br>` by using replace

```
str.replace("\n", "<br />","g");
```

Comment: -1 It be best to avoid a JS solution so that users who disable/can't use JS still have the strings render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is working now :

```
$query = "UPDATE your_table 
         SET your_text_field = 'line 1'" . '\n' . "'line2' 
         WHERE your_id_field = " . $id . "';";
```