# Convert Enter as new line from textarea tag into div tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

[Shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mrKn.png)

How I should convert new line when user press `enter` key as `<br>` tag inside `<div>` tag for result?

here's the codes:

```
<textarea>
    First text here //user press enter here 
    Second text here
</textarea>  

//AJAX to insert text to Database here...
```

**MySQL Procces**

```
//AJAX repond here... 

document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

**Result inside `<div>` tag**

```
<div id='sample'>
    First text here <br/>
    Second text here
</div>
```

Comment: you can use str_replace

Comment: Are you returning your data from `mysql` via `php`?

Comment: yes.. I pick it from MySQL via PHP..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php mysql storing line breaks in text area in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729524/php-mysql-storing-line-breaks-in-text-area-in-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use nl2br function in php:

```
$text = nl2br($POST['text_field']);
```

in javascript:

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {   
var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';    
return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nl2br Work Properly... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace()` to replace the enter(`\n`) to `<br>`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
text.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  result.innerHTML = text.value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```