# Line break issue with textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a project that saves user inputs from HTML form and get saved in MySQL db.

For example, I have this function

```
function funcGetRecordDetails(editID){
    $('#hiddenID').val(editID);
    var action = "get_record_teams";

    $.ajax({
      url : "teams_post.php",
      type : 'post' ,
      data : { editID : editID,
               action: action } ,
      success : function(data, status){

        var edit_data = JSON.parse(data);

        $('#mdl_update_team_order').val(edit_data.order_no);
        $('#mdl_update_team_team').val(edit_data.team);
        $('#mdl_update_team_names').val(edit_data.name);

      }
    });

  }
```

In my case `edit_data.name` will have line breaks. But `mdl_update_team_names` textarea is NOT displaying the line breaks properly.

For example, the data in DB is saved as `a\nb` and that is exactly how it will be shown in the textarea.

For testing purpose, I changed it to `$('#mdl_update_team_names').val('a\nb');` and the textarea IS displaying line breaks properly which is

```
a
b
```

Any idea how to display the line breaks properly from the DB?

Edit 1

When I do this, it works

```
var edit_data = JSON.parse('{"id":41,"snow_inc":"XXX","order_no":0,"team":"44","name":"a\\nb","update_by":"XXX","update_date_time":"2021-09-08 14:12:01"}')
```

But when I do this, it doesnt work.

```
var edit_data = JSON.parse(data)
```

But the response I'm getting is the same, which is

```
{"id":41,"snow_inc":"XXX","order_no":0,"team":"44","name":"a\\nb","update_by":"XXX","update_date_time":"2021-09-08 14:12:01"}
```

Tried this as well `var edit_data = JSON.parse(data.toString());` with the same results.

Comment: I would start by using the JS debugger, in your browser's developer tools, to see if `edit_data.name` does indeed contain `a\nb`, at the line where you assign its value to the text area.

Comment: check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729524/php-mysql-storing-line-breaks-in-text-area-in-database

Comment: I'm not sure, but it worth a try, I found [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574876/line-breaks-not-working-in-textarea-output), suggesting you could do: `.val(edit_data.name).replace(/\n/g, "<br>");` to replace `\n` by `<br>`.